# Best Solution for Drilling Up and Down on Large Sets of Data

Tags: database, olap

What type of system (columnular store, OLAP, Exadata, etc.) provides the best solution for drilling up and down through large data sets (400 million plus rows) at a rapid pace? I know this is a very vague question but how does columnular store DBs, OLAP environments, even OLTP such as Exadata compare with this type of activity?